# Orthophoto showing image banding along flight lines after reconstruction

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, photogrammetry, dji

I'm currently flying a mapping mission with a DJI P1 with the following flight parameters:

Altitude: 250m
Side/Forward Overlap: 60/80
Terrain Follow: Enabled
RTK: Enabled

Regardless of the time of day or flight direction, after reconstruction the orthophoto is displaying image banding that seems to correlate with the flight lines. I have processed in Pix4d Mapper, DJI Terra and Agisoft all give the same results. Any suggestions on what the problem is?

[image: Example Orthophoto.]

Comment: Have you tried increasing your side overlap?

Comment: @GBG Yes we increased it to 65% and the problem still seems to be present, however, due to the time constraints of the project we can not increase it further though.

Comment: Maybe your camera sensor is faulty or the lens was dirty and that resulted in the stripping?  Do the individual images look OK?